# why we have to write print('you are ' + str(32) + ' Years old' in python When

Tags: python

why we have to write `print('you are ' + str(32) + ' Years old')` in python when we can just write `print('you are 32 Years old')` to add a integer to string and both of them works perfectly fine

Comment: Well you can hard-code it, but the point is that the first form allows you to put some other expression (evaluated at run time) in place of the `32`.

Comment: How is this related to the `c++` tag?

Comment: What if you don't know the age until the person inputs the age into the program?

Comment: You **don't** have to do it that way.  If you always want to print 32 as the age, then you're free to use the full string method.

Answer (score 3):

yes, we can code as `print('you are 32 Years old')` in python, if we want it to always print that constant line.

when that 32 has to be grabbed from a variable, and if we surely know that variable type is a string we can use without the str() conversion. For example : `print('you are ' +x+ ' years old')`

When we do not know that the variable type will be always a string, we need to explicitly convert it to a string, `print('you are' +str(x)+ 'years old')`  .

without that `str(x)` , when this x is an integer, python would give this error:

```
>>> x = 32
>>> type(x)
<type 'int'>
>>> print ("you are "+ x + " years old")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'int' objects
>>> x = "32"
>>> type(x)
<type 'str'>
>>> print ("you are "+ x + " years old")
you are 32 years old
>>>
```

Comment: Thanks  You made this super crystal clear.
Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

TLDR:

You can't add a string and an integer together. You have to cast the integer to a string to add (concatenate) them.

THOUGHT THIS WAS FOR C++

Just like alani stated concatenating the strings with an express (in your example 'str(32)') allows the program to display more than what is hard coded.

For example, let's say your program asks the user their name and age:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
string name;
int age;

std::cout << "What is your name? \n";
std::cin >> name;

std::cout << "What is your age? \n";
std::cin >> age;

std::cout << "My name is " << name\n";
std::cout << "I am " << age << " years old";

return 0;
```

At runtime, the user will enter a string (their name) and an integer (their age), this can change depending on user input.

This program will output:

```
My name is: John Smith
I am 32 years old
```

However, your program is hardcoded meaning that every time it is run it will provide the same output.

First run:

```
My name is rjt
I am 32 years old
```

Second run:

```
My name is rjt
I am 32 years old
```

...nth run:

```
My name is rjt
I am 32 years old
```

Concatenating an expression and string for something as simple as a name and age might not seem like much now, but when you learn more complex programs it will be ***VITAL*** to your programs.

For now, just follow the steps from your tutorials and you should see the light soon!

Comment: I don't think that the OP was really asking about C++, it looks like they just tagged it for no good reason. But obviously similar principles apply.

Comment: Wow, I typed all of that for no reason. I could have just put to get the datatypes to match *rolling eyes emoji*.

Comment: Sorry, just tired experience with seeing too much of people adding random tags to their questions and suspecting that this is a case of this... As there is no evidence from the text of the question that C++ is actually involved, I'm going to edit the question to remove the tag to save anyone else from wasting time. [Update: looks like I can't because someone else is editing.]